# Animate images from array in javafx pane to scroll seamless in clip window

Tags: java, animation, javafx, observablelist

I am creating slot machine application with javafx. Desired behavior: separated pictures have to appear in pane as real slot machine drum during animation (pictures of cherry, lemon, number sever and etc should look like one whole peace for user) like showing on picture.

[slot machine](http://www.casinocashjourney.com/images/Slot%20Types.jpg)

My problem is I can't put together separate images to scrolling in slot machine window seamless. 
I have made a lot of search about this problem but didn't find any working solutions. I have tried to add all images in ArrayList and then set them as node to TranslateTransition reference during animation process. But initial image stack in windows.

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TestClass extends Application {

private BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
private GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    ImageView image1 = new ImageView(createImage(Color.RED));
    ImageView image2 = new ImageView(createImage(Color.GREEN));
    ImageView image3 = new ImageView(createImage(Color.BLUE));

    gridPane.setLayoutX(50);
    gridPane.setLayoutY(50);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);

    gridPane.add(image1, 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(image2, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(image3, 2, 0);
    gridPane.setMaxWidth(image1.getFitWidth() * 3);
    gridPane.setMaxHeight(image1.getFitHeight());

    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(732, 230);
    clip.setLayoutX(30);
    clip.setLayoutY(10);
    clip.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    // clip.setFill(null);

    gridPane.setClip(clip);

    borderPane.setCenter(gridPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 900, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("SlotMachine");
    primaryStage.show();

    ImageView[] images = { image1, image2, image3 };

    TranslateTransition t1 = new TranslateTransition();
    for (ImageView i : images) {

        t1.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        t1.setNode(i);
        t1.setFromX(image1.getX());
        t1.setFromY(image1.getY() - gridPane.getHeight());
        t1.setToX(image1.getX());
        t1.setToY(image1.getY() - image1.getFitHeight() / 2 + gridPane.getHeight());
        t1.setCycleCount(2);

        t1.setAutoReverse(false);
        t1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    }

    TranslateTransition t2 = new TranslateTransition();
    for (ImageView i : images) {

        t2.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        t2.setNode(i);
        t2.setFromX(image2.getX());
        t2.setFromY(image2.getY() - gridPane.getHeight());
        t2.setToX(image2.getX());
        t2.setToY(image2.getY() - image2.getFitHeight() / 2 + gridPane.getHeight());
        t2.setCycleCount(2);

        t2.setAutoReverse(false);
        t2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    }

    TranslateTransition t3 = new TranslateTransition();
    for (ImageView i : images) {

        t3.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        t3.setNode(i);
        t3.setFromX(image3.getX());
        t3.setFromY(image3.getY() - gridPane.getHeight());
        t3.setToX(image3.getX());
        t3.setToY(image3.getY() - image3.getFitHeight() / 2 + gridPane.getHeight());
        t3.setCycleCount(2);

        t3.setAutoReverse(false);
        t3.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    }

    ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition(t2, t3, t1);
    pt.play();
}

private final Image createImage(Color color) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(32, 32);
    rect.setFill(color);
    return rect.snapshot(null, null);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}
Please help. Thank you in advance

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: James_D I have edit my question. Is it more clear now or I have to provide more details? I am new in this community and not familiar with rules how to ask questions.

Comment: Please read the links in my previous comment

Comment: I have read these articles carefully and according to them revised my question. Please help to find solution of my problem. Thank you

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: James_D I have add code from my application that produce my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question so that others can simply copy and paste the code and run it (i.e. I turned it into a [MCVE]). If this makes it behave differently to your example (which couldn't be run without other resources) I will revert the edit. I don't really understand your code (maybe someone else does). `ParallelTransition`s execute a collection of other `Animation`s in parallel: since you only have one transition (`t2`) the parallel transition is redundant. Also, your `for` loop just repeatedly sets the same properties: you may as well just set them once.

Comment: James_D Thank you for your edit. I have added two more ParallelTransitions that animate other two rectangles. 'for' is adding new picture in ParallelTransition every new loop.

Comment: Your `for` loops are still doing nothing at all. For example, in the first `for` loop, the first iteration sets the node of `t1` to `image`. The second iteration sets the node of `t1` to `image2`. The third iteration sets the node of `t1` to `image3`. So you would get exactly the same effect by getting rid of the `for` loop entirely and just doing `t1.setNode(image3);`. What are you expecting the clip to do? And, one other thing: `getX` and `getY` on an image view are probably not giving you what you expect: they give the location of the image in the image view.

Comment: I am excepting from 'for' loop to change image during animation. But it doesn't work as I want. Clip is showing moving pictures just on GridPane  rather than on whole BorderPane.

Comment: Sorry, I probably can't be any more help here. I simply have no idea what your code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Ok Thank you for trying to help I am deeply appreciate

Answer (score -2):

From what I can tell, it doesn't look like you are using Model/View/Controller architecture; using this architecture is the easiest way (in my opinion) to implement a gui like this. In your case, you could model your logic from the following psuedo-code:

**In Controller:**

```
//changes x or y coordinate (depending on direction of movement) of top left corner
//the controller should change the values of x or y that are stored in your model    
moveImageMethod(image);
```

**In View:**

```
//Number of ms between timer events, play with this number to make it smooth
private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 1000/30;

//constructor
public View(){
    <your other stuff, event handlers, etc.>
    this.timer = new Timer(TIMER_INTERVAL, new ActionListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                   handleTimerTick(); 
            } 
     }); 
}

// Start the animation timer. 
public void startTimer() { 
       timer.start(); 
} 

protected void handleTimerTick(){
    controller.moveImageMethod(image);
    <other stuff you might need/want>
    repaint();
}

<your graphics methods>
```